# Ember deeply nested routes do not keep parent dynamic parameter

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-router, ember-model

I've got this ember application:

```
Ember       : 1.3.2
Ember Model : 0.0.11
Handlebars  : 1.3.0
jQuery      : 1.9.1
```

Using this resource map:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('dimensions', function() {
    this.resource('dimension', { path: ':dimension_id'}, function () {
      this.resource('value', { path: 'values/:value_id' });
    });
  });
});
```

And this allows me to embed `{{outlet}}` in "dimensions" template that fills with "dimension" template, and embed `{{outlet}}` in "dimension" template that fills with "value" template as well.

All works very well except for the link-to helper in the "value" template, that does not accept more params nor accepts other models as described in ember API documentation.

Which is the best way of dealing with link-to in deeply nested routes?

I've got this fiddle to show my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/vsiguero/pQpE3/5/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: The `paramsFor` method was added some time after I wrote this answer, which makes this possible. Refer to [@nickiaconis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871764/542251) for more details.

---

If I understand you correctly, I think you're running into expected behavior. The parameters for a route are unique to that route. I'm not 100% sure why that is, but dynamic segment values don't get passed to child routes. What you should do instead is access the model directly. In your `value` route, you can use `this.modelFor('dimension')` to get the model that was resolved for the `dimension` route.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I ended up using this workaround here, I leave it here just in case is useful for anyone: http://jsfiddle.net/vsiguero/pQpE3/8/

Answer (score 18):

You can access parent routes' parameters from a child route like so:

```
this.paramsFor(parent_route_name).param_name
```

So you'd do something like this in your `/app/routes/dimensions/dimension/value.js` file:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params, transition) {
    var dimension_id = this.paramsFor('dimension').dimension_id;
    // do whatever you need with dimension_id and params.value_id
  }
});
```

Here's a fork of your jsFiddle, modified and working: http://jsfiddle.net/niaconis/kxejh9yr/
Note that I updated Ember.

Here is the documentation for `Route#paramsFor`: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_paramsFor

Answer (score 6):

I believe the latest ember 1.5+ applies any models or literal values given to the `link-to` helper from child to parent so you don't have to provide models for the full model path as they will default to the current route path.

Also you have access to parent models via the transition argument passed into model() using transition.resolvedModels  from memory.  Each dynamic route segment in the route path will be an an attribute on that object so make sure your router DSL specifies distinct names for each segment parameter name (as you currently do).  So in your ValueRoute you can do something like:

```
model: function(params,transition) {
    return transition.resolvedModels.dimension;
}
```

Comment: In original question `link-to` is not working because Ember Routes are used improperly: instead of the current model, child models are loaded. But I needed this answer for other goals and found it here :)

Comment: This should use the public `Route#modelFor` API rather than the private API of the `transition` object.